# $wpdb select query by month, post type, and taxonomy term

Tags: wpdb

I'm trying to create a bar graph of post counts laid out in months within a selected post type and taxonomy.

I have this query which works exactly as it should but it doesn't include the selected taxonomy term.

```
$post_type_query = " AND post_type = '" . $selected_post_type . "'";

$posts_per_month = $wpdb->get_results(
                    "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(post_date, '%Y-%m') as month, count(ID) as count
                    FROM $wpdb->posts wposts
                    WHERE post_status = 'publish'" . $post_type_query .
                    "GROUP BY month",
                    OBJECT_K
            );
```

It outputs this which is perfect

```
Array
(
    [2016-11] => stdClass Object
        (
            [month] => 2016-11
            [count] => 1
        )

    [2016-12] => stdClass Object
        (
            [month] => 2016-12
            [count] => 10
        )

)
```

However, I can't seem to get it to filter the count down by a selected taxonomy term. This is what I've tried

```
        $posts_per_month = $wpdb->get_results(
                "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(post_date, '%Y-%m') as month, count(ID) as count
                FROM $wpdb->posts wposts
                LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta ON wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id
                LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON (wposts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
                LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
                WHERE post_status = 'publish'" . $post_type_query .
                "AND term_taxonomy = 'business'" .
                "GROUP BY month",
                OBJECT_K
        );
```

This outputs nothing as I'm guessing my sql is off. I'm not very knowledgeable of sql and it would be great to learn how to do this, I've been googling for hours with no progress.

Comment: What is **business** here at `"AND term_taxonomy = 'business'"` ? Is it a term or a taxonomy ?

Comment: Business is a term in a custom taxonomy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not joined the `wp_terms` or `$wpdb->terms` table where WordPress stores the term names. So here is the updated code-

```
$post_type_query = " AND post_type = '" . $selected_post_type . "'";
$posts_per_month = $wpdb->get_results(
    "SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(post_date, '%Y-%m') AS month, COUNT(ID) AS count
                FROM {$wpdb->posts} AS wposts
                LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} AS wpostmeta ON (wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id)
                LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} AS tax_rel ON (wposts.ID = tax_rel.object_id)
                LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} AS term_tax ON (tax_rel.term_taxonomy_id = term_tax.term_taxonomy_id)
                LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->terms} AS terms ON (terms.term_id = term_tax.term_id)
        WHERE post_status = 'publish'" . $post_type_query .
       "AND terms.name = 'business'
        AND term_tax.taxonomy = 'your-custom-taxnomy-name'",
    OBJECT_K
);
```

In above code put `terms.name` value as your term's name and `terms_tax.taxonomy` value as your custom taxonomy name like `category` or `post_tag`. Here `terms_tax.taxonomy` value is not mandatory, but it makes the result more precise.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. This seems to return a single post though and the array contains all the post info instead of the month and the count. If I remove `*,` after SELECT then it returns a count but the count is wrong. There are two posts with this term but it says there are 48. Before I removed `*,` [count] => 48 was returned as part of the one posts data in the array.

Comment: Oh wow. ok so I removed `*, ` after SELECT and then I removed the LEFT JOIN to the wpostmeta table and it seems to be working when the term doesn't have a dash in it. so 'business' returns properly but 'shoreline-or-waterway' returns an empty array. Do I need to escape those characters?

Comment: It is because of `GROUP BY month`. Just remove that part and it'll get you all the posts.  Cause by `GROUP BY month` it actually groups the posts by `month value`. How ever check my updated code.

Comment: I am actually looking to group them by month so that I can create a visualization of amounts of posts by term and post type over months. I tried your updated code but I still have the issue that it returns all the post information instead of just the month and the post count. My edit to your code seems to be working perfectly except when there are dashes in the term slug or spaces in the term title. Thanks so much for the help though I really appreciate it, I see what I was missing now and I guess I possibly have an entirely different issue now.

Comment: Could be another issue. If my answer helps you then would you please accept it ?